# Using stream to sort by value return from method

Tags: java

I have this method that returns a list of *environment* objects a *unit* can sense, but it does not return them in order of closest to farthest:

```
    List<Environment> = gameWorld.returnEnvironmentInCircle(unit.getLocation(), unit.getType().getSensorRadius());
```

I would like to create a stream of this list and re-sort it by the following value:

```
    unit.getLocation().distanceTo(environment.getLocation())
```

This function acts by simply calculating the distance between the unit sensing the environment and the environment object it is sensing.

This is my attempt but it obviously does not work:

```
           List<Environment> environmentList = gameWorld.returnEnvironmentInCircle(unit.getLocation(), unit.getType().getSensorRadius());
           List<Environment> environmentStream =   environmentList.stream()
                                            .sorted(environment -> unit.getLocation().distanceTo(environment.getLocation()));
           return environmentStream;
```

I'm sure there are multiple problems here, so I appreciate your help!

Comment: Does not look so bad; what is your specific problem?

Comment: Looks like you don't know how to impement such a `Comparator` in Java 8 style?

Comment: Why are you comparing every entry with `unit.getLocation`?

Comment: Because i need to know the distance between each environment object and the location of the unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea, but you forgot to create a `Comparator` to use in the `sotrted` method and collecting the stream back to a list:

```
List<Environment> environmentList = 
    gameWorld.returnEnvironmentInCircle(unit.getLocation(), 
                                        unit.getType().getSensorRadius());

List<Environment> sortedEnvironmentList =
    environmentList.stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                       unit -> unit.getLocation()
                                   .distanceTo(environment.getLocation()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

While this should work, it's worth noting that using a stream is a bit of an overkill - you could just use [`List#sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) directly:

```
List<Environment> environmentList = 
    gameWorld.returnEnvironmentInCircle(unit.getLocation(), 
                                        unit.getType().getSensorRadius());

environmentList.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(
        unit -> unit.getLocation().distanceTo(environment.getLocation()));
```

Comment: This worked great! I used your second solution. I only have to change unit -> unit.getLocation()....... to environment -> unit.getLocation().....

Answer (score 2):

`sorted()` expects a comparator. A comparator is basically a function that takes two Environment objects, and returns an integer. You're passing a function that takes a single environment, and returns a distance.

Moreover, you're trying to assign a `Stream<Environment>` to a variable of type `List<Environment>`

You're not far, though:

```
List<Environment> sortedList = 
    environmentList.stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(environment -> unit.getLocation().distanceTo(environment.getLocation())))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```